# How to change the search engine via CLI to use OpenSearch?

Tags: magento2, database, opensearch

I'm trying to install a store but I have an error related to the setup made with MySQL as the search engine, which isn't supported anymore.

```
Your current search engine, 'MySQL', is not supported. You must install a supported search engine before upgrading. See the System Upgrade Guide for
```

more information.

How could I say to Magento to use OpenSearch instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you already have **OpenSearch** running, you just need to configure it as my example below. I used Magerun 2 to easily do it.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
./var/n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname opensearch.magento2.docker
./var/n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port 9200
```

Then you can run setup upgrade and reindex.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar setup:upgrade
./var/n98-magerun2.phar index:reindex
```

Comment: but in config you are setting elasticsearch as search engine also config:store:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname opensearch.magento2.docker do we have to install any docker container to use this host or it will work. as it is. please explain a bit am trying to configure opensearch using port 9200 and search enginer as opensearch and host as localhost but its not running

Comment: @Pramod make sure your OpenSearch is running, then configure the engine as elasticsearch7